# Is there a scipy/numpy alternative to R's nrd0?

Tags: python, r, numpy, scipy

From the [R Documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/bandwidth.html)...

> bw.nrd0 implements a rule-of-thumb for choosing the bandwidth of a
>   Gaussian kernel density estimator. It defaults to 0.9 times the
>   minimum of the standard deviation and the interquartile range divided
>   by 1.34 times the sample size to the negative one-fifth power (=
>   Silverman's ‘rule of thumb’, Silverman (1986, page 48, eqn (3.31))
>   unless the quartiles coincide when a positive result will be
>   guaranteed.

On an array from 1 to 400 (equivalent to `np.arange(1,401)`), nrd0 will return 31.39367.  When I try to implement something similar in python...

```
def nrd0_python(x):

    X = min(np.std(x), np.percentile(x,25))

    top = 0.9*X
    bottom = 1.34*len(x)**(-0.2)

    return top/bottom
```

I get upwards of 200 (to be exact, 224.28217762858455)

Are there any known python functions for silverman's rule of thumb?

Comment: `np.percentile(x,25)` is not the same as the interquartile range.

Comment: Ah yes, that was very dumb of me. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have the right calculation for IQR:

```
import numpy

def bw_nrd0(x):

    if len(x) < 2:
        raise(Exception("need at least 2 data points"))

    hi = numpy.std(x, ddof=1)
    q75, q25 = numpy.percentile(x, [75 ,25])
    iqr = q75 - q25
    lo = min(hi, iqr/1.34)

    if not ((lo == hi) or (lo == abs(x[0])) or (lo == 1)):
        lo = 1

    return 0.9 * lo *len(x)**-0.2
```

This returns the same as the R function, which is given as:

```
> bw.nrd0
function (x) 
{
    if (length(x) < 2L) 
        stop("need at least 2 data points")
    hi <- sd(x)
    if (!(lo <- min(hi, IQR(x)/1.34))) 
        (lo <- hi) || (lo <- abs(x[1L])) || (lo <- 1)
    0.9 * lo * length(x)^(-0.2)
}
<bytecode: 0x0000000010c688b0>
<environment: namespace:stats>
```

EDIT: My original reading of the second `if` statement in the `R` code was incorrect, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38352572/how-to-interpret-double-or-and-assigment-in-if-clause). It is meant to capture cases where `lo == 0` (because `sd(x) == 0`), and in that case, where the vector is all zeros. If my understanding is correct, it should read:

```
if not lo:
    if hi:
        lo = hi
    elif abs(x[0]):
        lo = abs(x[0])
    else:
        lo = 1
```

Like the `R` code, you can shorten this to :

```
lo = lo or hi or abs(x[0]) or 1
```

It is important to include these checks, along with the check for the length of the vector.

Comment: FYI, I'm pretty sure my translation of the `if` clause is incorrect, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38352572/how-to-interpret-double-or-and-assigment-in-if-clause?noredirect=1#comment64117466_38352572.

Comment: I see you participated in that question. How would I implement the logical ors in Python? I suppose I could a series of if/elif. Is there a more economic way similar to R?

Comment: Nice.  However, to match R, the call to `numpy.std` must use `ddof=1`: `hi = numpy.std(x, ddof=1)`

Answer (score 3):

The precedence of operators in an English sentence is ambiguous.

Here's an implementation that returns the value you expect:

```
In [201]: x = np.arange(1, 401)

In [202]: 0.9*min(np.std(x, ddof=1), (np.percentile(x, 75) - np.percentile(x, 25))/1.349)*len(x)**(-0.2)
Out[202]: 31.393668650034652
```

I don't have the Silverman reference.  I found that in http://darp.lse.ac.uk/papersdb/Cowell-Flachaire_Handbook.pdf (p. 21).

Answer (score -1):

If you are working with KDE's can you just use scipy.stats.gaussian_kde?  It implements Silverman's and Scott's rules for bandwidth selection.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html

Comment: This is for a Nadaraya Watson smoother.  My understanding is that gaussian_kde returns the PDF of the random variable.