# How to interpret double "or" || and assignment in if clause

Tags: r, operators, variable-assignment

In the function source for `stats::bw.nrd0`, there is a complicated (to me) `if` statement:

```
> bw.nrd0
function (x) 
{
    if (length(x) < 2L) 
        stop("need at least 2 data points")
    hi <- sd(x)
    if (!(lo <- min(hi, IQR(x)/1.34))) 
        (lo <- hi) || (lo <- abs(x[1L])) || (lo <- 1)
    0.9 * lo * length(x)^(-0.2)
}
<bytecode: 0x0000000010c688b0>
<environment: namespace:stats>
```

Is `||` to be interpreted in a special way, compared to the regular operator `|`? Where/how is `lo` being assigned / re-assigned? How would this be written in "long form"?

Full disclosure, I tried to translate this function to a Python function [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38337804/is-there-a-scipy-numpy-alternative-to-rs-nrd0/38338389#38338389), so if you can answer this, you can also add a better answer to that question.

Comment: When logical OR is used in assignment, it typically means "if this first this is truthy, assign it to the variable, else assign the second thing. So it probably means" if hi is truthy, assign it, else assign abs(x[1L])". Disclaimer: I don't know r.

Comment: If this is correct, Python can do this like: `x = falsyVal or truthyVal`.

Comment: `"||"` is kind of short-circuit comparison (e.g. `TRUE || stop("reached")` VS `TRUE | stop("reached")`). In this case `lo` is being re-assigned until its value, _firstly_, evaluates to `TRUE`. E.g. `(x <- 1) || (x <- 2) || (x <- -1); x; (x <- 0) || (x <- 2) || (x <- -1); x` etc

Comment: So if `lo == 0`, we assign to whichever of `hi`, `abs(x[1])` or `1` is non-zero first, in that order?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to some helpful comments, I now understand that this means that if `lo == 0`, we assign to whichever of `hi`, `abs(x[1])` or `1` is non-zero first, in that order. In Python, we could write:

```
lo = min(hi, iqr/1.34)
lo = lo or hi or abs(x[0]) or 1
```

or more explicitly:

```
if not lo:
    if hi:
        lo = hi
    elif abs(x[0]):
        lo = abs(x[0])
    else:
        lo = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

From the help docs:

> & and && indicate logical AND and | and || indicate logical OR. The
>   shorter form performs elementwise comparisons in much the same way as
>   arithmetic operators. The longer form evaluates left to right
>   examining only the first element of each vector. Evaluation proceeds
>   only until the result is determined. The longer form is appropriate
>   for programming control-flow and typically preferred in if clauses.