# What is the Python equivalent (i.e. same output) for the R function density()?

Tags: python, r, scikit-learn, kernel-density

In R, there is a function called [`density()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/density). The syntax for the function is -

```
density(x, bw = "nrd0", adjust = 1, kernel = c("gaussian", "epanechnikov", 
        "rectangular", "triangular", "biweight","cosine", "optcosine"),
        weights = NULL, window = kernel, width, give.Rkern = FALSE, n = 512, 
        from, to, cut = 3, na.rm = FALSE, …)
```

Of the different parameters, the ones I normally use are `x` (a numeric vector from which the estimate is computed) & `adjust`. I leave the other parameters to its default value (`bw = "nrd0"`, `n = 512` & `kernel = "gaussian"`)

Is there a function in Python which takes the same (or equivalent) input AND **returns the same output**. The main output I am looking for are the 512 (since n = 512) x & y values.

Comment: I can't seem to find an actual equivalent (yet), so all I can give is a hint for making a function. To get the specified bandwidth (`bw = "nrd0`), you can use certain algorithms from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38337804/is-there-a-scipy-numpy-alternative-to-rs-nrd0).

Comment: I don't think you should expect an equivalent function to necessarily exist. There are implementations in different languages. `scipy.stats` has  various kde implementations, while `scikit-learn` has alternatives for visualization. they are not the same. But `R` and `Python` has excellent packages for bi-lingual programming. So if the output of `density` is what you want, install both on your machine and use [`rpy2`](https://rpy2.github.io/) to use the function from python.

Comment: Thanks @Oliver. I used rpy2 and am able to use the Density function in the same manner as my R script. I will post my code as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Oliver's suggestion, I used rpy2 to call R's density function from Python.

Code in R

```
column <- c(63, 45, 47, 28, 59, 28, 59)

output <- density(column, adjust=1) #all other parameters set to default

x <- output$x
y <- output$y
```

Code in Python

```
from rpy2 import robjects
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
from rpy2.robjects import vectors
import numpy as np

stats = importr("stats")

column = vectors.IntVector([63, 45, 47, 28, 59, 28, 59])

output = stats.density(column, adjust=1)

x = np.array(output[0])
y = np.array(output[1])
```