# Rewriting R's density() (not really)

Tags: python, r, function, typeerror, kernel-density

In response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65759744/what-is-the-python-equivalent-i-e-same-output-for-the-r-function-density), I took upon the challenge to make my understanding on R's [`density()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/density) function.

Since I'm pretty much very new to R, I have no ideas about vectors regarding the `c()` function, which made me use a list as the closest form.

I would make this function:

```py
def density(x, bw, adjust):
    bw2 = None
    result = 0
    if bw == "nrd0":
        bw2 = 31.39367
    else:
        print("No such bandwidth.")
    for i in range[len(x)]:
        x[i] = x[i] * bw2
    for i in range[len(x)]:
        result = result + x[i]
    return result * adjust
```

And I wanted to test it:

```py
x = [1, 3, 5]
kern = density(x, "nrd0", 1)
print(kern)
```

And I gained 2 errors, the main one being a `TypeError`.

If you want to look into it further, here's the whole terminal message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "density.py", line 15, in <module>
    kern = density(x, "nrd0", 1)
  File "density.py", line 8, in density
    for i in range[len(x)]:
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

How do I fix the `TypeError`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in range[len(x)]:
        x[i] = x[i] * bw2
```

You have `range` with `[]` while it should be `()`. Try to change it.
Below is an example:

```
l = [10, 20, 30, 40] 
for i in range(len(l)): 
    print(l[i], end =" ") 
print()
```