# Using rpy2 to reproduce density function, but get different output

Tags: python, r

I am trying to reproduce [density.()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/density) function from R.

I have studied the topic post on stackoverflow before [What is the Python equivalent (i.e. same output) for the R function density()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65759744/what-is-the-python-equivalent-i-e-same-output-for-the-r-function-density)

And I have succefully built my code, however I got different result in R and Python.

Below is my R code

```
set.seed(1234)
x <- rnorm(10)
dx <- density(x, adjust=1)
```

[image: my x and dx$x(which I expected to see same as output on python)]

And here is my python code, I copy the same x and use the following code

```
from rpy2 import robjects
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
from rpy2.robjects import vectors
import numpy as np
X = [-1.2070657, 0.2774292, 1.0844412, -2.3456977, 0.4291247, 0.5060559, -0.5747400, -0.5466319, -0.5644520, -0.8900378]
print(" my X: ", X)
print("\n")

stats = importr("stats")

column = vectors.IntVector(X)

output = stats.density(column, adjust=1)

x = np.array(output[0])
y = np.array(output[1])
print("dx$x from R : ", x[:10] )
print("\n")
print("dx$y from R : ", y[:10])
```

[image]
Also I am just trying to reproduce [density.()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/density) function from R using Python,

I understand there might not be equivalent function, however R documenation says that this function is just kernel density estimates, but I still can't reproduce same result using sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity with same parameters

Comment: I am trying to reproduce the result in Python using r2py.

But also I am looking for the equivalent function density.() in Python

Comment: Likey the difference are due to the seed. In Python, you have not set the same seed as in R, so there are minor differences

Comment: The seed only generate the X, I am using the exact same X(vector) so it sould be the same result, This is my thought, if I got anything wrong, please tell me

Answer (score 1):

A kindly person just remind me of my vectors.IntVector(x) is the reason why the bug happened, just replace with vectors.FloatVector(x) can reproduce the result.